# Extract two column values based on top 5 of one column, without grabbing the rest of the columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a sheet with all kinds of values, the most important ones:

Column B2 to 256: Color name
Column F2 to 256: Sold items

I need to grab the top 5 color names and amount of sold items, without grabbing the rest of the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention:

> ...grab the top 5 color names and amount of sold items, without grabbing the rest of the columns.

There are different ways to read your request

If your question is:

- Grab the top 5 color names ***(meaning 5 colors with most sold items)*** and amount of sold items, use the formula in `H3`

  ```
  =QUERY(A1:F,"select B, sum(F) where B is not null 
             group by B order by sum(F) desc limit 5 label sum(F) 'MOST Sold' ",1)
  ```

If your question is:

- Grab the top 5 color names ***(meaning top 5 colors as they appear in column `B`)*** and amount of sold items, use the formula in `H11`

  ```
  =QUERY(A1:F,"select B, sum(F) where B is not null and B matches '"&JOIN("|",(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE(B2:B),5,1)))&"' 
             group by B order by sum(F) desc limit 5 label sum(F) 'MOST Sold' ",1)
  ```

[image]

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)

If I misunderstood your question, please share a test sheet so as you can be easier helped.*

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`Array_CONSTRAIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036)
- [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077)
- [`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198)